# Libwebsockets Sending Data

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, libwebsockets

When I try to send data from client to server, it says "lwsts[9972]: error on reading from skt".. I have searched through internet and there is not a clear expression. I am sending the data as the test_server.c example does in the LibWebSockets package. Which mistake may cause this problem? I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send data from a client to a server you'd be better off looking at [test_client.c](https://github.com/ayosec/libwebsockets/blob/master/test-server/test-client.c) rather than test_server.c. More information would be good. When are you seeing the error, on connection, when trying to send?